# Parse throught mails in sent items folder in a shared mailbox

Tags: python, email, winapi, outlook

I'm trying to parse throught sent mails in a shared mailbox. 
I can parse throught folder inside the mailbox, but impossible to get the mails inside the folders.

The code I use:

```
compteur= [i for i in range (11)] #Number of mailbox i have to work with
    for i in compteur:
        if i !=0:
            outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
            namespace = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
            root_folder = namespace.Folders.Item(i)
            for j in root_folder.Folders: # (if i print (j), i can get the folders list of each mailbox )
                for k in root_folder.Folders.Items:
                    print(j) # i get a AttributeError: <unknown>.Items with this code.
```

Comment: Items property is for the MAPIFolder object. Just use " for k in root_folder.Folders:"

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was close to the solution !

Comment: I’m back to work so i can test the answer. And it don’t work. Thus, if i print k it will give me the folders names for each mailbox, but will not parse throught mails inside the folders. I tryied with for k in root_folders.Folders[« sent items »] of give me a com_error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to process subfolders, you access the `MAPIFolder.Folders` collection. If yo uwant to process the items, you access the `MAPIFolder.Items` collection.

You really need to create a function that takes MAPIFolder as a parameter. That function can process `MAPIFolder.Items` and then calls itself recursively for each subfolder in the `MAPIFolder.Folders` collection

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm drowning in work. I want to thank you, your solution was the good. I created an intermediate path with the folder i need for each mailbox, and the item method works fine with this new path. Really thanks for this speed lesson !

Comment: If the reply answers your question, please mark it as such. Thanks!